# Is it a good idea to build a db layer of a webpage only with REST WebServices?

Tags: security, rest

We want to build a website, which interact with database only with REST WebServices. So if we want to build a mobile app later, the app can simple use these WebServices. So we thought we will use Python/Django or PHP/Yii to build the database layer, made only of REST WebServices. In the frontend backbone.js interact with the WebServices to do CRUD-Operations with the database.

Is that a good idea with regard to performance and security? How do big sites and apps handle the interaction between frontend and database layer nowadays?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think this is a bad idea but only slightly.

Instead of having a logic-less CRUD only array of web services why not instead create an array of functional web services. That way you can keep your business rules server side.

Maybe you already had this in mind but consider that whether the user is on your mobile app or your website you don't want them creating usernames with strange characters in them. A strictly CRUD array of web services wouldn't check for these kinds of business rules.

Comment: yes i had business rules server side in my mind. May it came out all wrong. But is this a good idea to provide the data only with rest webservice. Even for the web frontend? How can i secure the communication? Is it enough for the [webfrontend <> data layer] to limit the access to the rest webservice with a htaccess?